# Save CMSampleBufferRef Before Sending it to AVAssetWriter

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to save some samples in `didOutputSampleBuffer` delegate before writing it to album with `AVAssetWriter`.

This is the code for saving the samples:

**.h file**

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger audioIndex;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger videoIndex;

@property (nonatomic) CMTime startTime;

@property (nonatomic) CFMutableArrayRef audioSamples;
@property (nonatomic) CFMutableArrayRef videoSamples;
```

**.m file**

```
CFRetain(sampleBuffer);
if (CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer)) {
    if (self.videoIndex == 0) {
        self.startTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
    }
    if (bVideo) {
        int count = 0;
        count = (int)CFArrayGetCount(self.videoSamples);
        if (count >= 1000) {
            CFArraySetValueAtIndex(self.videoSamples, self.videoIndex, sampleBuffer);
        }
        else {
            CFArrayAppendValue(self.videoSamples, sampleBuffer);
        }
        self.videoIndex = (self.videoIndex + 1) % 1000;
    }
    else {
        int count;
        count = (int)CFArrayGetCount(self.audioSamples);
        if (count >= 1000) {
            CFArraySetValueAtIndex(self.audioSamples, self.audioIndex, sampleBuffer);
        }
        else {
            CFArrayAppendValue(self.audioSamples, sampleBuffer);
        }
        self.audioIndex = (self.audioIndex + 1) % 1000;
    }
}

CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
```

The problem is the last line `CFRelease`, 
when calling this method I cannot use the samples for later purpose getting error:

> [Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

And when not calling this method the video images stuck and "not responding" (but the instance is available).

Comment: Anyone knows the answer?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be setting up a pair of ring buffers for audio and video. But you are releasing the CMSampleBuffers that you have placed onto your ring buffers - so when you need to access them they are not there. The quick fix is to only release a CMSampleBuffer when you overwrite it on your ring buffer with a new sample. Whenever you write a sample to the ring buffer, you should check whether an existing sample will be overwritten at that index, and CFRelease it only at that point.

*However* this is not really going to work out as you will be breaking the CMSampleBuffer memory model which will result in dropped frames or worse.

Here is what the [Apple docs advise](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009762-CH1-SW3):

> If your application is causing samples to be dropped by retaining the provided CMSampleBufferRef objects for too long, but it needs access to the sample data for a long period of time, consider copying the data into a new buffer and then releasing the sample buffer (if it was previously retained) so that the memory it references can be reused.

[WWDC 2011 video 419, Capturing from the Camera using AV Foundation on iOS 5](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) includes, in it's list of Do's and Dont's (pdf p.50):

> - DON't hold on to sample buffers outside of the data output callbacks
> - DON't take a long time to process buffers in the data output callbacks

[Here](http://www.programering.com/a/MTM0AzMwATM.html) is an example  using buffer copying (not mine - I haven't tested it). Note the caveat: "But there is another problem, that is the memory of super large, so this is for video to be used with caution."

You may need to rethink your design. Whatever processing you are planning to do with your ring buffer content, perhaps at least *some* of that could be undertaken *before* adding data to your ring buffer, so that you are not holding onto the CMSampleBuffers themselves but rather data that has been processed (and hopefully less memory-intensive).